# Best pratice to insert string into HTML file using node

Tags: node.js

Suppose I have a large HTML-file, and at a few places I want to insert a string, which content is set during startup. How would I solve this if I'm only allowed to deliver a static HTML, hence everything has to be handled on the server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JADE](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme) templating engine. If it will be static all the time, you can compile the templates to your public directory and serve them with a framework like [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have this HTML file, I would suggest use of [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/).

Rewriting anything to haml (jade) is just too much work...